# JavaFX 2: locking slider

Tags: javafx-2

At last I found something to ask.
I am working on small JavaFX project with animation. There is a Slider then sets Transitions' duration. **How can I lock the Slider before animation is started?**

I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException at SequentialTransition, beacuse I stop animation when Slider value is changing. So at first it tries to stop null Transition:

```
void stopAnimation(){
    seqT.stop();
}
```

Everything works just fine, except when someone moves slider before animation is started :).
I tried to disable slider in constructor, and enable it within EventHandler which starts animation, but it doesn' work:

```
slider = SliderBuilder.create()
        .disable(true)
```

and then

```
.onAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
         @Override
         public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
               if(!"Stop".equals(startBtn.getText())){
                    startBtn.setText("Stop");
                    slider.disableProperty().setValue(Boolean.TRUE);
                    startAnimation(60/slider.valueProperty().doubleValue());
                }                                                    
                else {
                    startBtn.setText("Start");
                    stopAnimation();
                }
           }
           })
```

Comment: May be you should set disable to false to enable it?

Comment: Instead of slider.disableProperty().setValue(Boolean.TRUE); you can use slider.setDisable(true);

Comment: OMG :), it works both ways. And in both should be "false". (sometimes one get desperate beyond any reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable slider back you need to use

```
slider.setDisable(false);
```